# attaching image using camera in android

Tags: android, email, camera, attachment

I am working on a project where I have two choices, either I click a photo and the same `image` is attached to the mail and can be sent. The second is I select the `image` from the `gallery` and the image selected is sent as an attachment in the `mail`.I am able to do the later part but have problem in attaching image after clicking it using `camera`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button select;
ImageView photo;
EditText et_subject, et_message;
TextView tv_attach;
String subject, message;


private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
 Uri URI = null;
 Uri URI1= null;
 int columnindex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    select = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    et_subject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et_message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv_attach = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    photo.setOnClickListener(this);     
    select.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageView1:
        selectImage();
        break;

    case R.id.button1:
        subject = et_subject.getText().toString();
        message = et_message.getText().toString();

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"example@xyz.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        if (URI != null || URI1 != null)
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);

        startActivity(emailIntent);
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
            {
                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions); 

                photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                URI1 = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
                //f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            URI = Uri.parse("file://" + picturePath);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
            photo.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've tried something but seems I'm wrong.

Please help me what can be done? Can anybody make changes in the code that I've used?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it worked for me, hope it helps!

```
    mail_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fake@fake.edu"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"On The Job");
        //Log.d("URI@!@#!#!@##!", Uri.fromFile(pic).toString() + "   " + pic.exists());
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pic));

        i.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share you on the jobing"));
    }
    });


} 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
 thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


    try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()){
             pic = new File(root, "pic.png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic);
            thumbnail.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("BROKEN", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }   

}  
}
```

Comment: can you make changes in the code I've given. I mean edit my code to be the right code? Can that be done?